# How to get data from all pages by selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to get data from all the pages from the link that shown in the below code, but don't work.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from time import sleep
from scrapy import Spider
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('http://buyersguide.recyclingtoday.com/search')
results = list()
#scrpae data here
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@style='font-weight:bold;']//parent::tr")
#get more pages 
while True:
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Next').click()

                sleep(15)

                #scrpae data here
                rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@style='font-weight:bold;']//parent::tr")

                for i in range(0, len(rows)):
                    print(rows[i])

                    results.append(rows[i])

                    print('---')


            except NoSuchElementException:


                break
#get all the wanted data 
records = [] 
for result in results:
     company=result.find_element_by_xpath('./td[1]').text
     address = result.find_element_by_xpath('./td[2]').text
     contact= result.find_element_by_xpath('./td[3]//a').text
     number= result.find_element_by_xpath('./td[5]').text
     records.append((company,address,contact,number))
#output to be table 
 df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['company','number','address', 'contact'])
```

Comment: what does not work? are you getting any exception?

Comment: You post IS mostly code... with little to no explanation. What exactly is the problem? It "don't work" isn't very descriptive. It's not reasonable to dump code and expect us to run it and tell you what the issue is. The expectation is that YOU run the code and do some investigating and debugging on your own. Once you've done that and you are still stuck, then you post 1. what are you trying to do (in words), 2. how you are attempting to do it (in code, an [mcve]), and a description of what isn't working (including error messages), sample HTML or a link to the page, and what all you've tried.

Comment: .I checked the code, and run it, and no error appeared , but just can not get the data, such as company, contact , number etc. but if i run the code one by one on jupyter notebook, it is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer to your questions as there is not explanation of the problem you are facing. However, I took a stab at it. This is not unit tested and if you are going to leverage this implementation, use webdriver wait in place of time.sleep and do unit test

I got the data but did not test if all the data went into the iframe

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import pandas as pd

driver = Chrome(executable_path=<path>)
driver.get('http://buyersguide.recyclingtoday.com/search')
results = []

while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    results_table = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#Body_tbl>tbody')
    rows = results_table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
    del rows[:2] # delete header
    del rows[-2:] # delete footer
    for row in rows:
        data = row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
        results.append([data[0].text, data[1].text, data[2].text, data[4].text])

    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        next_ = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next >')
        next_.click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
       break

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Address', 'Company', 'Contact', 'Phone Number'])
```

Comment: I checked the code i wrote, and run it, and no error appeared , but just can not get the data, such as company, contact , number etc. but if i run the code one by one on jupyter notebook, it is ok

Comment: hi, sir, this code works, but a small problem,data[2] i don't want to get text, actually it have href, and i want to get the href may i know how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

try this (indentation may be broken):

```
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Next').click()
#sleep(15)# you can use explicit wait time as below
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[@style='font-weight:bold;']//parent::tr"))
rows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td[@style='font-weight:bold;']//parent::tr"))
for i in rows:
    text= i.text
    print text
```